# Creating my own callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with some jQuery, and a separate non-jQuery function.

Currently my function runs on $(document).ready, but I want to call a jQuery function as soon as my function is finished. I can pass my function as a callback to any jQuery function, but how can I set things up the other way round?

So I would ideally like to know how to create a function foo that will take care of this for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  foo(myfunction(), $(bar).something);
}
```

or how to extend an existing function to handle callbacks. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define your function to accept an (optional) callback, then use the javascript [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) method if the callback exists.  To retain the context, pass the current value for `this` (or whatever context you want) to the apply method.  Call() and apply() differ based on how arguments are passed.

```
function myfunction(callback) {
    // do stuff
    if (callback) 
        callback.apply(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is create your custom method to accept another variable...in this case, a function reference.

If you had something like this:

```
var add = function(a, b){
    return a+b;
};
```

To add a callback, you'd change it to this:

```
var add = function(a, b, callback){
    callback();
    return a+b;
};
```

(extremely poor example, but it gets the point across)

Comment: Do this with jQuery long enough and you'll find that losing the context (this) will become a real problem.

Answer (score 2):

What about function-wrapping:

```
Function.prototype.appendCallback = function(callback){
  var fn = this;
  return function(){
    fn.apply( this, arguments ); // execute original function
    callback.call(this);         // then the callback
  };
};
```

Example:

```
var newConfirm = window.confirm.appendCallback(function () {
  alert('after from callback');
});

newConfirm('hello?'); // shows a confirmation, and then executes the callback.
```